# QueueBrowser does not return all messages

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I list down queues and messages from each queue. The following is my code. But, QueueBrowser does not retrieve messages correctly.

Let's say, I have a queue named TestQueue which has 1000 message.

first time i run my program it shows only 200 messages.
second - 400
third - 600
forth - 800
fifth - 1000

Can you tell me how to fix this problem?

```
ConnectionFactory out = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=10000");
ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) out.createConnection();

connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Set<ActiveMQQueue> amqs = connection.getDestinationSource().getQueues(); 
Iterator<ActiveMQQueue> queues = amqs.iterator(); 

while ( queues.hasNext() ) 
{ 
    ActiveMQQueue queue_t = aqueues.next(); 
    String q_name = queue_t.getPhysicalName();
    List<ActiveMQMessage> msgList = ((ActiveMQSession) session).getUnconsumedMessages();

    System.out.println( "\nQueue = " + q_name);

    QueueBrowser queueBrowser = session.createBrowser(queue_t);
    Enumeration e = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();

    int numMsgs = 0;
    while(e.hasMoreElements()) 
    {
         Message message = (Message) e.nextElement();
         numMsgs++;
    }
    System.out.println("No of messages = " + numMsgs);
    queueBrowser.close();
}                    
session.close();
connection.close();
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Ralf, Not yet. I also notice that even Web Console can retrieve 200 messages at first time. Then, at second time of trying to browse again, msg count increased to 400. next 600, 800. I checked Web Console codes and found that it also used QueueBrowser.

Comment: my current solution is to consume all message without acknowledging. So, i can get all messages and still able to maintain them in queue. but, i feel that it is not reliable. next solution is to browse queue again and again till the max msg count is met.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: No, I did not resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Calling getEnumeration multiple times doesn't return next batch of messages as well. I always get the same set of messages.

Comment: @LwinHtooKo Did it retrieve only pending messages or all messages ??

Answer (score 3):

From the `javax.jms.QueueBrowser` API:

> Messages may be arriving and expiring while the scan is done. The JMS API does not require the content of an enumeration to be a static snapshot of queue content. Whether these changes are visible or not depends on the JMS provider.

Have you tried specifying the [prefetch policy](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html)?

Comment: thanks for the answer but the behavior is the same after adding prefetch policy. I edited the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect using JMX to Broker (use jconsole for example). On specific queue set MaxPageSize properties more than 200 then you can list more messages.